# Why my .split(' ') doesnt work?

Tags: python, split

I've been trying to override the first input for `fullname` under object "Pete Tong" and change it to "James Milner" using the `split` function.

However, when I run the below code, all output except for printing of the `fullname()` returns the "Pete Tong" first and last name, which I was trying to change for all accesses.  Any idea why?  I thought it should be printing all as "James Milner" with the override.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    @property
    def email(self):
        return "{}.{}@email.com".format(self.first, self.last)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)

    @fullname.setter
    def fullname(self, name):
        first, last = name.split(' ')
        self.first = first
        self.last = last


emp_1 = Employee('Pete', 'Tong')

emp_1.fullname = 'James Milner'

print emp_1.first

print(emp_1.first)
print(emp_1.email)
print(emp_1.fullname)
```

Comment: What is your output and what is the expected output?

Comment: Works as expected as far as I can see? Prints "James" for `emp_1.first`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using Python 2, and your class is not inheriting `object`.  You can either (a) Use Python 3, or (b) Change the class definition to:

```
class Employee(object):
```

which will work in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated so explicitly, but I suspect that you're running Python 2 on a feature that works only in Python 3.

The one `print` without parentheses implies that you're running this with Python 2.  `setter` works only in Python 3.  That also explains how another user can get `James` from your code (after fixing that one print).

To fix this in Python 2, you need your class to inherit from the mother-of-all, `object`:

```
class Employee(object):
```

Python3 does this automatically; Python 2 does not.

Comment: I think OP is using python3, because of the print function and statement at the same place.

Comment: Perhaps -- but when I remove the redundant `print` and run this in Python 3, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to for properties to work you need to use new style classes which inherit from object, so declare your class like this, it will work

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    @property
    def email(self):
        return "{}.{}@email.com".format(self.first, self.last)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)

    @fullname.setter
    def fullname(self, name):
        first, last = name.split(' ')
        self.first = first
        self.last = last


emp_1 = Employee('Pete', 'Tong')

emp_1.fullname = 'James Milner'

print emp_1.first

print(emp_1.first)
print(emp_1.email)
print(emp_1.fullname)
```